# Move existing control

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, libreoffice-writer

I am creating a PDF form in LibreOffice Writer. I have some controls and want to move them. Referring to the screenshot, I want to  move the Date of Request label and the Date control above the Name and Title controls. If I drag the Date of Request upward, it will not go above the Name and Title label. How do I do this?

[image: screeshot]

I get this error after lots of dragging the label around:

[image: Nonfunctional]

Comment: Did you try to instead drag the Name and Title down?

Comment: Yes, when I do that, then the Date of Request goes down as well, staying below the Name and Title. Interestingly, I can move the Date control above the Text Box.

Comment: You might need to drag down the fields in order to make space at the top.

Comment: I've tried dragging every which way. Sooner or later, the application crashes. See addition to question.